# ASP.Net rebuilds on each request

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net application, installed on a 2003 server.

I have a main installation on a dir called X, and a test installation installed on a dir called X_test.

When I installed a new version of my code to X_TEST - that web site (the one on the test) rebuilds the dlls on each request, resulting in a very slow response time.

When i copied the bin from X to X_test - it worked ok, but when I used the new bin, I get the build on every request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of it, I found out that somewhere in the our code, it writes a file to the bin directory and deletes it.

This triggers asp rebuild mechanism, and that's what caused the problem

Comment: Just in case you don't already know: If possible, you should write files to the *App_Data* directory rather than the *bin* directory.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of four hour of work, we have create a new virtual directory x_test2, with a new physical location, and that resolved it.